# Does "the truth is deceptive" make any sense or should it be " truth can be deceiving"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Does "the truth is deceptive" make any sense or should it be " truth can be deceiving" ?

Comment: Please provide the context, and its full sentence. Fragments of sentences are just that, fragments, we cannot get a clear idea from a single broken piece.

Comment: Oh well... no response. 1) Yes 2) Depends. I'm voting to close this question for lack of research.

Comment: Context : A conversation between two friends 'A' and 'B' :            A: I've seen you lose your cool on a couple of occassions you really need to calm down.                                          B : The truth is deceptive

Comment: It should be: *Appearances can be deceiving*. Please **edit your post**, it's much clearer now. Other users will come up with different suggestions, justify your choice or even reject mine.

Comment: It's been edited, do go through it again. :)

Comment: No, I mean to know if "the truth is deceptive" makes any sense,irrespective of the context in which it has been used.
 Ps: I've searched the net and it hasn't been used anywhere.

Comment: Google disagrees, the expression exists, there are [46,300 results](https://www.google.it/search?q=he+truth+is+deceptive&oq=he+truth+is+deceptive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22the+truth+is+deceptive%22)

Comment: Top two links lead to the questions that I've posted and barring one other link , "truth is deceptive" hasn't appeared anywhere .( Verbatim)

Comment: http://freemarketcafe.com/2014/07/truths-of-omission-nar/ and http://aestasbookblog.com/nocte-review/ and [The truth is deceptive brain messages](http://www.jackihayes.com/whats-holding-back-positive-change/) That's why I asked for a full sentence.

Comment: This settles the argument i've been having with a friend,thanks alot :)

Comment: You could also say: *The truth is misleading* (This is for the folks out there.)

Comment: "Truth is deceptive" is a sweeping statement, and, incidentally, is untrue, do not say that. "Truth can be deceiving" is a fact, and obviously what the OP means to say. Also, in any given context, the sweeping statement takes away the force, while the conditional brings emphasis to the possibility as a warning/ caveat.

Comment: It's valid syntax, though of course of somewhat less than total validity in a logical sense.  Perfectly valid in a "poetic" sense, and may be quite "meaningful" in general writing/speech if the context of the statement makes it understood that "the truth" being discussed is the truth about a particular thing, not "truth" in general.

Comment: Does "'the truth is deceptive' makes any sense, irrespective of the context". Absolutely not as it completely confounds logic. In your formulation Truth=Deception and, therefore, Deception=Truth. It's self-negating. If any sense is to be taken from such a statement it all lies in its context, Semantically it equals nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't mean the same thing, because in the second one you have introduced *can be*, which allows for doubt.

But ***the truth is deceptive***, would be the same as saying ***the truth is deceiving***.

Comment: So you mean to say "the truth is deceptive" could actually be right ( provided it fits the context)

Comment: Yes. But I would be happier if you gave us the full context.

Comment: A : You still spend alot of time viewing XYZ shows
B : No i dont, the truth is deceptive .

Comment: Within that context, the expression is inappropriate and confusing. I would suggest that the idiom: [*Don't judge a book by its cover*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_judge_a_book_by_its_cover) fits better.

Comment: Yes. I agree with @Mari-Lou A. That is not an appropriate context. Try: *The truth, namely that he is overweight, is deceptive. He is still a good athlete.*

Answer (score 0):

Should I say

- I run every morning
- The toothache hurts
- My dog eats cheese

or should I say

- I like running every morning
- Toothaches can be hurting
- My dog may be eating cheese

?